# What is the S3 hostedZoneId input used for?

Tags: amazon-s3, pulumi

Digging through our Pulumi code, I see that it sets the `hostedZoneId` on the S3 bucket it creates and I don't understand what it's used for.

The bucket holds internal content (Pulumi state files) and is not set as a static website.

The Pulumi docs in [AWS S3 Bucket hostedZoneId](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/s3/bucket/#hostedzoneid_nodejs) only state:

> The Route 53 Hosted Zone ID for this bucket's region.

with a link to what appears to be an irrelevant page (looks like a copy-paste error since that link is mentioned earlier on the page).

[S3 API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html) don't mention the field either.

[Terraform's S3 bucket docs](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws/latest), which Pulumi relies on many times but is also a good reference for S3 API in general, exposes this as an output, but not as an input attribute.

Does anyone know what this attribute is used for?

Comment: It provides a programmatic way of getting the hosted zone ID [from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints) (I don't think there's an API to get this, rather Pulumi has a [hardcoded list](https://github.com/pulumi/terraform-provider-aws/blob/72e8bb4fc26feac0f06860453e931972d6eb2528/aws/hosted_zones.go) )

Comment: @AnonCoward your response must be referring to the output from the resource. I'm asking about the input parameter.